# Creating a 3-Level Hierarchical Sanity.io Schema for Efficient Content Management

Tags: schema, content-management-system, hierarchical-data, sanity, content-management

I need help creating a Sanity.io schema that allows me to structure content in a hierarchical manner like the following:

```
- Hub 1
 - Guide 1
        - Chapter 1
        - Chapter 2
 - Guide 2
        - Chapter 1
        - Chapter 2

- Hub 2
     - Guide 1
            - Chapter 1
            - Chapter 2
     - Guide 2
            - Chapter 1
            - Chapter 2
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired content structure using Sanity.io or another CMS? Or would it be more efficient to build a custom admin page to manage this hierarchy? Any advice on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Currently, I've managed to create a Guide page and then create chapters separately. After that, I link each chapter one by one to the Guide page. However, this approach becomes problematic when there are 100+ chapters because all chapters will be mixed together, making it difficult to manage chapters belonging to different topics.